# filter not working with anonymous function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to learn react so I know this isn't the best way to make a copy but why doesn't the following work:

```
var allItems = this.state.items;
allItems =allItems.filter(function(e){return e;});
```

I keep getting filter is not a function

Comment: Make sure `allItems` is an array.

Comment: Are you sure that `this.state.items` is an array? Perhaps it needs to be set to `[]`initially?

Comment: You can reduce this to `allItems.filter(e => e)` though I don't understand why, you're returning everything, nothing is being "filtered". Are you trying to turn something into an array?

Comment: thanks, allitems is an object {}

Comment: There's your problem, `filter` an an Array method, not an object method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `this.state.items` is an Object, not an Array, you will need to loop over the keys like so:

```
var filteredArray = [];
Object.keys(allItems).forEach(function(key) {
    // do something with each item
    console.log(key + ': ' + allItems[key]);
    // like add it to a filtered array, conditionally if you want to:
    filteredArray.push(allItems[key]);
});
```